# Reset current date selection in angular date picker

Tags: angular

My date picker is working as per the UTC date. So when I open the date picker at `12:01AM`, it's default selection (on the current date) is still on the previous date as shown in the below image.
Here I set the system time as `Aug 2 12:10AM`. But Selection is still on the `Aug 1st` itself.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                          <mat-label
                            >Date Of Birth
                            <span style="color: red;">*</span></mat-label
                          >
                          <input
                          readonly
                            [max]="today"
                            formControlName="dateOfBirth"
                            matInput
                            [matDatepicker]="pickerxx"
                            (click)="pickerxx.open()"
                            
                          />
                          <mat-datepicker-toggle
                            matSuffix
                            [for]="pickerxx"
                          ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                          <mat-datepicker #pickerxx></mat-datepicker>
                          <mat-error
                            *ngIf="dateOfBirth.invalid && dateOfBirth.errors.required">
                            {{ alertMessage.dobReq }}
                          </mat-error>                              
</mat-form-field>
```

Here my ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

public addPeopleForm: FormGroup;
public today = new Date();

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,    
    private tService: TimezoneConversionService
) {}

get dateOfBirth() { return this.addPeopleForm.get('dateOfBirth'); }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.today = this.tService.convertToLocalTimeZone(new Date());  
    this.initAddUser(); 
}

initAddUser() {
    this.addPeopleForm = this.formBuilder.group({    
      'dateOfBirth': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),               
    });       
}
```

How can i make this working in default timezone?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUezO.png)

Comment: Are you using reactive forms? Please include the TS code that handles this form control.

Comment: I suggest you just give it the date without time